# How to provide a specific node template in a custom module

Tags: 8, theming

I am using a custom module and using Bartik theme(from Drupal 8 core module) and hence need to define a content type specific template like node--[type].html.twig

I added hook_theme in my custom module as follows

```
function custom_autofill_reference_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path){
   drupal_set_message($path);
   return [
    'node' => [
      'path' => $path . '/templates',
      'template' => 'node',
    ],
  ];
}
```

but not sure on how to add a content type specific template in a custom module without the need to create a custom theme?

Comment: You mean a content type specific template in a custom module without the need to create a custom *theme*?

Comment: yes @4k4, I found the solution , I will send an answer for the same.

Answer (score 5):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function custom_theme() {
  return [
    'node__custom_content_type' => [
      'base hook' => 'node',
    ],
  ];
}
```

Then make sure that you have the content type template under `custom/templates/node--custom-content-type.html.twig`